# SSRS 2016 Automate deployment to SQL Server 2008R2 using rs.exe

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2017, ssrs-2016

Currently the reports we have are written using Visual Studio 2012 and SQL Server 2008 R2. We also use the `RS.exe` utility to automate the deployment of our reports to our different environments.

We are looking at jumping to Visual Studio 2017 and using the newest SSRS project templates, etc.  We can change the target SQL Server version as part of the project settings and deploy back to the SQL Server 2008 R2 instance fine within Visual Studio.

The problem is that it seems that the automation tool (`rs.exe`) doesn't have the ability to specify the Target server version and as such we can't use it to push any reports automatically.  This kind of defeats the purpose of even starting to use Visual Studio 2017 UNTIL we upgrade our SQL Server to 2016.

Are there any workarounds to allow us to use VS 2017 and continue to AUTOMATE the push of reports into the older SQL Server 2008 R2?  Or is the only option to deploy directly from VS 2017 using the Target SQL Server edition setting.

Thanks.

Comment: i have been working on my own Report deployment program for a while, i would suggest you dont use RS.exe and rather use rsdeploy...learn the ins and outs of reportingservice2010 and make a few alterations to the rsdeploy

Comment: best part about RSDeploy is that its a CMD c# app, so you can automate deployment via the correct input.(Im using my own version of RSDeploy from dev to production)

Comment: If you like i could drop my code for you, it includes a how to guide :)

Comment: But I don't think that RSDeploy would address the issue that I'm talking about.  Visual Studio must change the .RDL file when you specify the Target SQL Server version in the VS Project settings screen so that it can deploy to a lower version.  Is there a way for RSDeploy to change schemas so that the RDL file isn't rejected by the lower SQL Server version?

Comment: RSDeploy uses reportingservice2010...if reportingservice2010 cant work with ssrs2008 then use reportingservice2005 :)

Answer (score 1):

Using [ReportingServicesTools](https://github.com/Microsoft/ReportingServicesTools/) could help you with the automatic deployment.
Build the report with VS as you see fit and set the version in VS. Then, use the script to copy from where your .rdl files are to the API of the SSRS server.